# Half-life vs mean lifeitme. Book error?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, textbook-erratum, isotopes, half-life

This text is from an scholar book (to editors: please, keep original and translated text):

> La vida mitjana d'un isotop es de 50 anys. Calcula el temps necessari
>   perque l'activitat es reduexi al 40%.

Translation:

> The mean lifetime of an isotope is 50 years. Calculate the time required
>   for the activity to be reduced to 40%.

Official answer is 66.1 years

However, for mean lifetime $ \tau $ equal to 50 years:

$ 0.4 = e^{- \frac{t}{\tau} } $

$ t = -ln(0.4) \, \tau = 45.8 \, \text{years} $

If I assume half-time $t_{1/2} $ of 50 years (instead of mean lifetime 50 years):

$ 0.5 = e^{- \lambda \, t_{1/2} } $

$ 0.4 = e^{- \lambda \, t } $

I obtain $\lambda = 0.0139 \, \text{years}^{-1} $ and the value given as correct answer: t=66.1 years.

Is me or is the book that is confusing half-time with mean lifetime ?

Comment: Can I ask what language that is? It looks like Spanish and French were put in a blender. (But also, it doesn't look like Portuguese or Italian)

Comment: @ThePhoton: thanks for your comment. It is catalan, that, as you noted, is a brother of spanish and french.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the half life is $t_{1/2}$ we can't write

$$x(t)=e^{-t/t_{1/2}}.$$

Rather we should write

$$x(t) = 2^{-t/t_{1/2}}.$$

Then for your problem you'd have

$$0.4 = 2^{-t/t_{1/2}}$$

$$-\log_2(0.4)=\frac{t}{t_{1/2}}$$

$$t = -t_{1/2}\log_2(0.4)$$

$$ t=-t_{1/2}\frac{\ln 0.4}{\ln 2}$$

$$t\approx 66.1\ {\rm years}$$

Comment: My apologizes, in the translation "vida mitjana" must be "average life" not "half-life" as I wrote in the initial version of the question. Fixed in new version of the question.

Comment: Your answer confirms me that 66.1 years is the correct answer for half-time equal to 50 years. It is the clarification/verification I need, thanks a lot.